# Bounding box and collision detection code snippets for Adobe flash professional Cs5.5

Tags: collision-detection, code-snippets, bounding-box, flash-cs5.5

I am creating a very basic Game in Flash Professional CS5.5 and wanted to know if anybody had any Code Snippets for a bounding box for the character, and a collision detection Code Snippet.

The game consists of a player moving out the way to avoid cars and other obstacles while getting scored for how long they run.

Answer (score 0):

ours is 3D, C#
[Ape physics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aphysicsengine/) 
the entire engine is [here](https://aphysicsengine.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/aphysicsengine/trunk/src/)

take a look at convex hull and environment

we used a bounding volume hierarchy

a simple method of optimisation is to put a sphere around every object. when testing two objects for a collision, check if the centers of the objects are within the radius range. if the bounding spheres don't collide then no more work needs to be done.